# addEventListener() sobre múltiples <select>

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, laravel

estoy intentando crear una función en JavaScript/jQuery (me valen ambos), que me guarde el valor seleccionado (option) de un select, el problema es que este select se encuentra dentro de un bloque foreach, ya que la estructura final que genero es una tabla, en la que una de las columnas tiene tantos select como filas haya en la tabla, y, por tanto, al final obtengo varios select sobre los que quiero aplicar mi función JavaScript. Actualmente con este código me funciona lo que quiero hacer PERO sólo con el primer select que me aparece en la tabla, con el resto de select generados en el resto de las filas de la tabla, la función javascript no se activa...

```js
function myFunction(){
  var select = $("#selectedGamesToRate")[0];
  select.addEventListener("change",
    function(){
      selectedGame = this.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
      alert(selectedGame);
      $("#starButton").attr("href", "rate_your_order/"+selectedGame);
    });
}
```

```html
<tbody>
  @foreach($ordersByUser as $order)
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select id="selectedGamesToRate" onclick="myFunction()">
          <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose here</option>
          @foreach($orderedArticles->where('order_id', $order->id) as $orderedArticle)
            <option>
              {{ $articles->where('id', $orderedArticle->article_id)->first()->name }}
            </option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
        <a id="starButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

No sé como hacer para que el código javascript se aplique a todos los select dentro del foreach() y no sólo al primero...
Es un poco lioso y seguro que no me he explicado del todo claro, pero agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda...
Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al hacer foreach, no puedes asignarle un id ya que debe ser único para cada uno, en su lugar asigna una clase y en js asigna un listener

```
<select class="select_container">
  @foreach()
    @if($art = $articles->where('id', $orderedArticle->article_id)->first()->name)
        <option value="{{ $art }}">{{ $art }}</option>
    @endif
  @endforeach
</select>

<script>
    $(() => {
        $('.select_container').on('change', changeSelect);
    });

    function changeSelect (){
      var selectedGame = $(this).val();
      alert(selectedGame);
      $("#starButton").attr("href", "rate_your_order/"+selectedGame);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Jonathan Orta, al aplicar este código me da el siguiente error!: Undefined offset: 1

in CompilesLoops.php line 95

Comment: Ya me ha funcionado!!!! muchísimas gracias por la ayuda Jonathan Orta!!! decir también que he aplicado algunos de los cambios indicados por @Francisco Romero para que funcionase, como por ejemplo quitar el ID en el buttom por un class, así que muchas gracias a los dos por la ayuda!!

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema está en que estás utilizando un ID en vez de una clase para referirte a los distintos select. Los ID son para indicar un ÚNICO elemento dentro del HTML mientras que las clases se utilizan para identificar varios elementos que tengan el mismo patrón.

Tendrías que sustituir

```
<select id="selectedGamesToRate" onclick="myFunction()">
```

por esto:

```
<select class="selectedGamesToRate" onclick="myFunction(this)">
```

Si te fijas, en la segunda opción hago referencia a la palabra reservada `this`, lo que significa que haces referencia al objeto sobre el que estás pulsando.

Después en tu función simplemente haz: `var select = parametro;` y te obtendrá el select que estés pulsando en cada momento.

Para el botón también tendrías la misma problemática ya que tendrían todos los botones el mismo ID, aunque en este caso aplicarle una clase tampoco sería una buena solución (porque ¿cómo sabría el botón a que select le pertenece?).

Por lo tanto, se me ocurre que le puedes pasar el ID del order a la función como parámetro (a la vez que el `this`) y asignarle un ID diferente a cada uno de los botones. Algo así:

```
<a id="starButton-{{$order->id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="">
```

De esta manera cada botón tendría su ID correspondiente y dentro de la función podrías hacer referencia al botón que le corresponde a cada select de la siguiente manera:

```
var boton = "#starButton-" + parametro2;
$(boton).attr("href", "rate_your_order/"+selectedGame);
```

Comment: Entiendo @Francisco Romero, muchas gracias voy a probarlo!!

Comment: Ahora me funciona el alert en todos los select! antes ni siquiera eso ya es algo xD, sin embargo, el valor seleccionado en los otros select parece que sigue sin guardarse..., ya que mi intención es coger ese valor seleccionado y pasarlo a otra vista, me está funcionando en el primer select pero no en el resto!

Comment: @Franziskaner Fijate en que tu botón también tiene el mismo problema. Tiene un ID y se repite para los diferentes select. Deberías cambiarlo por una clase.

Comment: Serían así los cambios @Francisco Romero?: ` function myFunction(parametro){
            var select = parametro;
            select.addEventListener("change",
              function(){
                selectedGame = this.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
                alert(selectedGame);
                $("starButton").attr("href", "rate_your_order/"+selectedGame);
              });
        } `  `<a class="starButton" href="">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
  </a>` es que no me funciona y puede que la esté liando!

Comment: @Franziskaner He editado mi respuesta. Prueba a ver si así te funciona.

Comment: Sigo probando este método por curiosidad y por valorar tu tiempo @Francisco Romero, sin embargo, me surge la duda de como pasar ese parámetro2, ya que la llamada a la funcion la hago desde el select con un único parámetro: ` onclick="myFunction(this)" `  y no desde el propio botón, no sé si me explico.

Comment: @Franziskaner a la función le puedes pasar el id del order, a lo que me refiero es a esto: `onclick="myFunction(this,{{order->id}})"`

Comment: Me ha funcionado perfectamente @Francisco Romero. Muchísimas gracias!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Con esto `var select = $("#selectedGamesToRate")[0];` siempre vas a agarrar el mismo elemento (el primero).

La solución es `var select = event.target`. Con esto agarras el elemento en el cual ocurrió el evento.